# copy entire folder on postbuild to a specific folder

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Lets say ,
I have xyz.dll in the debug folder, along with resource files folders , de, da ,etc.
F be the project name  .

Folder Structure as mentioned below 
d:A\B\C\D\E\F\bin\debug

I have to copy the dll and resource file folders from debug folder to C1 folder .

Folder structure as shown below
d:A\B\C1.

available macros are 
TargetDir : d:A\B\C\D\E\F\bin\debug
ProjectDir: d:A\B\C\D\E\F\

I tried this but its not working

xcopy $(TargetDir ) $(ProjectDir)........\c1 /R /Y

This copies only the dll not the resources folder .
Any suggestions on how I should do this ?

Comment: If memory serves: Specify /S (or /E to include empty directories)

Comment: Add the /S to include subdirectort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a way ,

xcopy $(TargetDir)*.*$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\C1 /R /Y /E .

There is an * operators surrounding the dot(.) after the $(TargetDir) ,As its not visible when i post it , I'm mentioning it here .

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/S` switch to xcopy to include subdirectories recursively

`/?` is your friend..

```
C:\>xcopy /?
Copies files and directory trees.

XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B] [/J]
                           [/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...]

  source       Specifies the file(s) to copy.
  destination  Specifies the location and/or name of new files.
  /A           Copies only files with the archive attribute set,
               doesn't change the attribute.
  /M           Copies only files with the archive attribute set,
               turns off the archive attribute.
  /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
               If no date is given, copies only those files whose
               source time is newer than the destination time.
  /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
               Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
               should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
               strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
               copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
               example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
               all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
               .obj extension respectively.
  /P           Prompts you before creating each destination file.
  /S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
  /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
               Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
  /V           Verifies the size of each new file.
  /W           Prompts you to press a key before copying.
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
  /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
               assumes that destination must be a directory.
  /Q           Does not display file names while copying.
  /F           Displays full source and destination file names while copying.
  /L           Displays files that would be copied.
  /G           Allows the copying of encrypted files to destination that does
               not support encryption.
  /H           Copies hidden and system files also.
  /R           Overwrites read-only files.
  /T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
               include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes
               empty directories and subdirectories.
  /U           Copies only files that already exist in destination.
  /K           Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.
  /N           Copies using the generated short names.
  /O           Copies file ownership and ACL information.
  /X           Copies file audit settings (implies /O).
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
  /B           Copies the Symbolic Link itself versus the target of the link.
  /J           Copies using unbuffered I/O. Recommended for very large files.

The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.
```

Comment: Nope .still the same case .I think the problem is in the destination folder there is no folder structure available , meaning there are no folders for specific resource da , de . Is this the problem ? If yes How do I create the folder structure ?

Comment: You can set the Copy To Output Directory propety of the resource files
Alternatively you can do a sencond xcopy picking them up from thier base location, ie
xcopy $(ProjectDir)\Resources C1 /R /Y type stuff

Comment: I have tried even that ,for some reason its not working. Any other options .I think the problem is the folder structure is not available in the destination directory .Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: 'I have tried even that' -> actual code, actual errors